# jQuery function sometimes doesn't run

Tags: jquery

I have the following function, basically used to set an iframe height to the height of it's content:

```
$("#MSOPageViewerWebPart_WebPartWPQ1").load(function()
        {
            var Height = document.getElementById('MSOPageViewerWebPart_WebPartWPQ1').contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;

            document.getElementById('MSOPageViewerWebPart_WebPartWPQ1').height = Height;
        });
```

The vast majority of the time this will run as expected, but on the odd occasion it will take numerous reloads of the page before it works. Of course trying to debug it is fruitless as it always seems to hit the function and work.

Anyone any idea why it might not work every time?

Comment: Does this happens on all browsers?

Comment: Only testing on IE8 as this is what all of the users will be using. Also with some of the "nuances" of SharePoint we've decided to focus on IE.

Comment: you tried to put this inside $(function{ }) ??

Comment: It seems to work fine on FF and Chrome but I haven't tested thoroughly with them. As I say it is a rare occurance, but one I'd rather do without.

Comment: @alexl - It is inside `$(function() {});`

Comment: If it's inside $(), there's no need to use load(). They're both kind of onload functions, one generic and one specific

Comment: MSOPageViewerWebPart_WebPartWPQ1 is loaded dynamicly ?

Comment: Yes MSOPageViewerWebPart_WebPartWPQ1 is loaded dynamically by Sharepoint, but it's id never changes.

Comment: I've run into a similar situation where the site could be accessed in 2 ways (http://www.blah.com and http://blah.com no www).  This caused a security issue and the iframe's document could not be accessed.  Perhaps see if there's a similar situation here, someone running under a different url which maps to the same place.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(function(){
$("#MSOPageViewerWebPart_WebPartWPQ1").load(function()
        {
setTimeout(function(){
            var Height = document.getElementById('MSOPageViewerWebPart_WebPartWPQ1').contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;

            document.getElementById('MSOPageViewerWebPart_WebPartWPQ1').height = Height;
        });
},100);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why using 'getElementById'. Try using the jQuery build-in Selector mechanism:

```
jQuery("#MSOPageViewerWebPart_WebPartWPQ1").load(function() {
    // not sure, if this row work's fine in every context, try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926916/how-to-get-the-bodys-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript/11107977#11107977
    var scrollHeight = jQuery(this).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;

    jQuery(this).height = scrollHeight;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. Sometimes no scripts are run. However, I think this is a connection problem. When I'm not connected to the Internet and just view my website (with a browser using its file path, e.g. file:///C:/Users/Alejandro/Dropbox/Prices/index.html), the page takes quite a time to load (which is weird because it's lightweight), after that the content is displayed but none of the scripts are run.

I suppose it delays when loading the page because the browser is trying to download the jQuery source.

**So**, what I'd do is to include a Jquery fallback. **[More info in xandercoded's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387403/jquery-doesnt-always-load)**.

Although that would be stupid if you set your website online, because the user would already need Internet connection to download your site (and thus the jQuery would be downloaded).