# javascript - get the content of a div inside an iframe in a js in the main page

Tags: javascript, iframe

Good day to all.

I have this structure

```
  <html>

         <iframe>

                <div id="idd">Some Content</div>

         </iframe>       

         <script type="text/javascript">
                 function getIddContent()
                 {
                      //This is the part I ask about
                 }

                 var content = getIddContent();
         </script>
  </html>
```

I need to get the content of the div inside the content variable. Thank you for your time. If I use document.getElementById("idd").innerHTML it says that the div doesn't exist.

Comment: Try looking into this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926916/how-to-get-body-content-of-iframe-by-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code

```
function getIddContent() {
    return window.frames[0].document.getElementById('idd').innerHTML;
}
```

But you probably have to include the iframe contents via the src attribute on the iframe.

Comment: I get permission denied... I forgot to mention the iframe is not on the same domain... is on the same server but I don't think that helps.

Comment: If it's not on the same domain, it's impossible to get access to the contents, because that violates the cross domain policy. Sorry.