# How do I get this child html element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an iframe that looks like this:

```
<iframe id="iframe2" ...>
    #document
        <html>...</html>
</iframe>
```

I am trying to get the item underneath the `iframe` with the `html` tag.
In JavaScript, when I do:

```
document.getElementByID("iframe2")
```

this returns the correct iframe.

However, when I do this:

```
document.getElementByID("iframe2").childNodes
```

the return value is `[]`.

`document.getElementByID("iframe2").getElementsByTagName("#document")` and `document.getElementByID("iframe2").getElementsByTagName("html")` also return `[]`.

How do I access that `html` tag?
Also, what is that `#document` tag called?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926916/how-to-get-body-content-of-iframe-by-javascript

Comment: Sounds very much like this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/javascript-get-element-from-within-an-iframe

Comment: There's something wrong. What is #document exactly? Isn't it just a text? Mixing text with html tags can result in the whole content considered as a text node.

Comment: @Kamyar `#document` is not a real child node; it's a placeholder inserted by Chrome dev tools (possibly Firebug as well?) that represents the iframe's `contentDocument` property.

Comment: @Kamyar #document is just what it looks like. When I do an inspect elements, there is a "#document" nested inside the iframe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
document.getElementByID("iframe2").contentWindow.document
```

Or, the variant not supported by older IE,

```
document.getElementByID("iframe2").contentDocument
```

This will get you the `document` object of the embedded page, and from there you can use `.documentElement`, `.body` or `.head` properties to get the html/body/head DOM.

If you want the `window` object of the embedded page, use `contentWindow` instead of `contentDocument`.

MDN has a guide to [iframe scripting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/iframe#Scripting) that you will probably find helpful.

Comment: I get "null" or "undefined" when I try either of those. I also get a "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame" error

Comment: That means the frame is cross-domain.  For security reasons, you cannot access an iframe with a cross-domain origin.  (Imagine if any page on the Web could just open your Gmail inbox and search through the DOM of the page -- a security disaster.)

Comment: Yea this is it. The frame is cross-domain. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code:

```
var a = document.getElementById("iframe2").firstChild;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
var a = document.getElementById("iframe2").getElementsByTagName("*")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the URL for the IFrame content have the same domain as the parent page? If not, you won't be able to access anything inside the IFrame due to the same-origin policy.