# get element by id within an iframe

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get body content of iframe by javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926916/how-to-get-body-content-of-iframe-by-javascript)

I am creating a Chrome extension and I want to be able to access an element within an iframe. So far I am able to access the iframe, but when i go to access the element I want it returns the error "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'getElementById'". the canvas element in the iframe has id of "canvas".

```
    var divElement, iframeElement, canvasElement;

    if (document.getElementById("puzzle")) {
      divElement = document.getElementById("puzzle");
      iframeElement = divElement.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
      canvasElement = iframeElement.getElementById("canvas");
      console.log(canvasElement);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the iframe have a different domain from the site that's trying to access it? Cross-site scripting is prohibited by the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), and this may be why you are not seeing the element you want.