# how to get iframe body text using javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, innerhtml

here are 02 pages:

**iframe_content.php**

```
Some content is here.
```

**iframe.php**

```
<iframe id="sumon_iframe" src="iframe_content.php"></iframe>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  var iframe_id=document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].id; //i get it perfectly
  var content=iframe_id.body.innerHTML; //i don't get value
  alert(content);
</script>
```

How do I get the `iframe`'s `innerHTML` (`Some content is here`)in iframe.php page using Javascript?

Comment: watch out for cross-domain restrictions

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the body's content of an iframe in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926916/how-to-get-the-bodys-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

you must use

```
iframe.contentDocument
```

or

```
iframe.contentWindow
```

for ie

Comment: iframe.contentWindow gets the iframe's window. The equivalent of iframe.contentDocument is iframe.contentWindow.document

Comment: Sorry i get "undefined" message for alert

Comment: @user1911703 you'll have to wait until the frame loads before you get its content.