# If in iframe show/hide divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to show/hide different page elements if the page is loaded in an iframe

`<script>this.top.location !== this.location && (this.top.location = this.location);</script>`

works fine to escape the iframe, but

`<script>this.top.location !== this.location && (document.getElementById("toolbar").style.display="none");</script>`

doesn't hide my div with the id "toolbar". What am I doing wrong? (My javascript knowledge is very limited). Many thanks.

Comment: Can you post an example of this? Create a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @webfrogs it is not easy to crate a fiddle when working with iframes and stuff.

Comment: @user1608180 Check the CSS of your toolbar after your script changed the style of the toolbar (Use the Inspector bar of your favorite browser, dont use IE). Is there the display: none ? And if it is, is it overritten by another style? Maybe use css !important to be sure your style dont get overritten by another

Comment: @nbar No, I can't see display: none for the toolbar CSS. I get an error when loading the page within an iframe (not in its own window): 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null'

Comment: That error means that getElementById is returning null. Are you sure your div has the toolbar id?

Comment: Thanks, the id was correct, but the div hadn't loaded yet. Moved the script lower down and now works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

try to use jQuery!
you should use selector like the following:
first select iframe element, then find in this:

```
$("#myIframeId").contents().find("#your_element_id").hide()
```

the similar question was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755347/getting-contents-of-iframe-with-pure-javascript)

Comment: he is inside the iframe, not outside