# jQuery multi-domain Element Setting

Tags: jquery, iframe

I know that jQuery doesn't allow multi-domain access into iFrame's. I'm wondering if there is a workaround somehow?

I'm simply trying to set the text inside an input box to a pre-defined username from my DB.

I'm currently getting this error:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://domain.com" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "http://track.domain.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must
>   match.

Which is expected as jQuery's documentation clearly states it's not possible using the `.contents()` function: https://api.jquery.com/contents/

I'm simply curious if there is a workaround to this somehow?

```
$('#myframe').contents().find('#ext-comp-1001').val('username');
```

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfreak53/8L2pJ/

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't access anything or manipulate iFrame content if its from a different domain. This is the purpose of an iFrame. Check [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe), [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755347/getting-contents-of-iframe-with-pure-javascript)

Also from [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentdocument.asp)

`Note: Because of security reasons, the contents of a document can be accessed from another document only if the two documents are located in the same domain.`