# Prefilling form on extern webpage

Tags: javascript, html, forms, iframe

There's some website (not mine, it's third party) that has a form on it. In order to spare the user from having to fill out this form, I want to somehow prefill it with data I have stored in my database.

Let's say it looks like this:

```
<form id='form1'>
  <input type='text' id='input1' />
  <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

I though a solution would be to create my webpage, and on it create an iframe with the form I want to fill.

```
<iframe id='myFrame' src='http://www.someSite.html'>
```

I have followed some suggestions here about how to access content in an iframe: [Getting Contents of Iframe with Pure JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755347/getting-contents-of-iframe-with-pure-javascript), [How to get the body's content of an iframe in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926916/how-to-get-the-bodys-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript#answer-2141057), but the problem is, when I follow them, it says that the content of the page is null.

I found out that it's because the page with the form is on a different domain, so web browsers don't allow it. It's possible to turn this off in the browser, but I need it to work independently of browser settings.

Comment: You can ONLY do it with a proxy on your server OR a bookmarklet

Comment: Often sites will populate form fields with corresponding query string data in the URL, try that. For example: `http://www.someSite.html?text=UserInputHere` Won't work for all forms but might work for yours.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you're asking in a simple web page. The security restrictions exist for a reason; imagine if a malicious user wanted to load, say, your banking site in an iframe and have you login. The malicious script on the hosting page would then have access to the form where you enter your credentials, account information, etc, etc.

As @mplungjan stated, you have to work around this by either making requests from your server and proxying them, so that the remote content actually goes through your site first, or by getting the user to modify their browser environment with a plugin or a bookmarklet.