# iframe content not displaying on chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am trying to display a p tag inside an iframe. Both files are on my desktop, so there is no issue with different domains. I am able to visualize the p tag in IE but not in chrome or firefox running the following line

```
    document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document.getElementById('p').innerHTML =" ";
```

Is there a cross-browser alternative to this approach?

Comment: [Getting Contents of Iframe with Pure JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755347/getting-contents-of-iframe-with-pure-javascript)

Comment: [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Comment: hi @Brian, unfortunately the links you provided did not solve my problem... any other thoughts?