# access object in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

So I'm trying to access an object in an iframe within my script printed below:

```
<script>document.getElementsByName("submission")[0].click();</script>
```

This works fine without the iframe, but as stated by question I'm unable to access this object when it's contained within Iframe!

What I've tried so far is giving the IFrame an ID and doing this:

```
<script>window.frames['NAME'].document.getElementByName("submission")[0].click();</script>
```

Why does this not work? And what should work?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/927023/1533609

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the javascript was loaded before the DOM so by loading the script after using the  thingi was the solution :)

Kind Regards!

Answer (score 0):

*Use*:

`document.getElementById('iframeName').contentWindow.document.getElementById("submission")[0].click()`

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#Scripting

*Edit*:

See demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cqq96/

*Security Note*:

If the content of the iframe is from a different domain, then you may not be able to access depending on the security levels. e.g. read up on `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` and its implications.

Comment: document.getElementById(...).contentWindow.document.getElementByName is not a function

Comment: @David O yes. Corrected.

Comment: @David have you checked the fiddle?

Comment: Sorry for the delay I'm doing this in a lab at school! It seems the problem was that the javascript was executed BEFORE the DOM was fully loaded so I had to do this in the BODY .. onload=CODE

Comment: Good that you were able to track it down.