# Access iframe contents on external web site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Can i access contents of I-frames using JS or JQuery? when I try to access contents from external links it gives access control error. Please give me some hints to access contents of I-frame that includes external link.
http://development.yourpersonalshopper.com/VirtualShoppingAddressTest.php

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: you have to proxify it server side

Comment: you can load other site content into iframe. it depends whether you can use it or not.

Comment: restricted by `same origin policy`

Comment: copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926916/how-to-get-the-bodys-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript ?