# javascript changing of textbox in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to js and wrote the following

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function setIframeText() {
var iframe0 = document.getElementById('iframe0');
var iframe0document=iframe0.contentDocument||iframe0.contentWindow.document;
var cookieValue = getCookie('auf_name');
iframe0document.getElementById('jform_title').value = cookieValue;}</script>
```

So I have a HTML where I have an iframe with the id iframe0 and the textbox in the iframe hast the id jform_title. I want to set the value of the textbox in the iframe out from the parenty document, I tried it with my script and a button but it didn't work. It should change the value to the value of the cookie "auf_name".

Comment: does the iframe url start with the same domain name?

Comment: yes it's on the same domain @MehranHatami

Comment: If you want to check if a cookie exists by that name try alerting it `alert(cookieValue)`

Comment: @user3125470, have u set the cookie 'auf_name' earlier

Comment: that's not the point I am sure the cookie exists because I already created it before with php @Zword

Comment: yes I already set it before with php @girishlalwani2010

Comment: make sure if `cookieValue` has value or `iframe0document.getElementById('jform_title')` is not null. use alert to check them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend please make this function and rerun your code and please share with me what are u getting in the alert window

```
function getCookie(){
alert(cookie_variable);
}
```

Comment: Thank you I already realized the problem
I copied the getCookie function but didn't know that it first needs to be declared. So I copied it from there also and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this this [How to get the body's content of an iframe in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926916/how-to-get-the-bodys-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript)

Note: Please, always you should check if the solution exists in other post.
Well, You should check if you scripts is hosted in same domain, Also review if you don't have restrictions from server, the server could deny your access via scripts to iframes. You can find out to using google chorme debug.

Comment: I already searched and came to the solution I used above, but I am not sure if I did right with the cookie or maybe something else is the problem

Comment: Well, First check if you script is placed in same domain, Also review if you don't have restrictions from server, the server could deny your access via scripts to iframes. You can find out to using google chorme debug.

Comment: it says reference error getCookie is not defined
do i need special libraries for that function, I am not sure how this works in js

Comment: OK it was my fault I didn't define getCookie function. I am new to js and thought its already built in.

Comment: Oh understand, I imagined the getCookie function is not defined ;) Good luck !