# How to get the content of body in iframe and store it in a new div?

Tags: javascript, iframe, getelementbyid

How can I get the content of the body in an `iFrame` and store it in a new `div`? For example:

```html
<div class="area">
    <iframe  id="e_iframe" class="pt">
        #document
        <html>
            <body>
                BODYContents
            </body>
        </html>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Can I store the content `BODYContents` in:

```html
<div id="myid"></div>
```

with JavaScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the body's content of an iframe in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926916/how-to-get-the-bodys-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript)

Comment: this question is half of already answer above link but how to store in div tag.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work for what you need:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('e_iframe'),
    icontent = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document,
    bodyEle = icontent.getElementsByTagName('body'),
    content = bodyEle[0].innerHTML;

document.getElementById('myid').innerHTML = content;
```