# change another html files with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a sample `html` file.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="sample1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="sif" src="if.html"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

how can add text or elements in the `if.html` with `sample1.js`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926916/how-to-get-the-bodys-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript

Comment: I don't know if this is your real code, but keep in mind if the iframe HTML content is originating from other domain no modification would be possible.

Answer (score 1):

thanks  kingdamian42.
yes its work.

`sample1.js`

```
function getFrameContents()
{
    var iFrame =  document.getElementById('sif');
    var iFrameBody;
    if ( iFrame.contentDocument ) 
    { // FF
        iFrameBody = iFrame.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    }
    else if ( iFrame.contentWindow ) 
    { // IE
        iFrameBody = iFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    }
    alert(iFrameBody.innerHTML);
}
```