# Add class for interior iframe html elements using Jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe

Hi friends I have tried to add class for iframe html elements using jquery but I can't, I dont know how. could you explain how can this be possibly done. I tried to add class for iframe using query

```
$("iframe").addClass("myClass");
```

it worked for iframe but I want to add the class inside the iframe elements in jquery could you help me in this to solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the function `contents()` to get the document inside the iframe, and then you have to use the function `find()` to select the element inside the iframe.

```
$("iframe").contents().find("#element").addClass("myClass");
```

Comment: I tried this but It didn't work could you explain this in the iframe elements can we put iframe id and in the find the element can we put class name ?

Comment: jQuery("#ssf_M00zMjM0NkzSNTQ2ttQ1STFO0k1MMwGyjI2SjC0MDcyNDI0A").contents().find("#35656").addClass("test"); can we add like this it will work or not?

Comment: yes if our iframe's id is `ssf_M00zMjM0NkzSNTQ2ttQ1STFO0k1MMwGyjI2SjC0MDcyNDI0A` and the id of the element inside the iframe is `35656`

Comment: its not working for me dont know why its causing but it showing error like this Blocked a frame with origin "http://192.168.1.116" from accessing a frame with origin "http://app-siwiw8.sharpspring.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match. not show any errors in the console

Comment: it because cross-origin access is denied. if you own the page inside the iframe you can solve this problem, otherwise you cant, read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 2):

This solution is working well.
First you need to create javascript function like this

```
function addingClass()
{
    $("#iframe").contents().find("#element").addClass("myClass");
}
```

Then on your iframe control just add onload="addingClass();"

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

Check [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

`$("iframe").contents()` gives access to the html-elements inside the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
$("iframe").contents().find('YourElemnet').addClass('myClass')
```

See for more Info : [contents](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)

Comment: could you explain this in the iframe elements can we put iframe id and in the find the element can we put class name ?

Answer (score 1):

1. First get the iframe with JS. [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/927023/9225733)
2. Add the CSS file to the iframe [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/577002/9225733).

Then you can use all the CSS you want. :)