# Get content from iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to get content from an iFrame?

```
<p class="title">Here I want to insert .moviename's content which is in iframe</p>

<script>$(".title").html($("#myIframe").contents().find(".moviename"));</script>
```

Comment: Seems right, this should work.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926916/how-to-get-the-bodys-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript

Comment: This looks right to me. That said, it will only work if the iframe content is on the same domain due to the same origin policy

Comment: @Siguza Yeah, I took js code from there

Comment: @Carl Isn't there alternative version? The website which from I want to get contnet, isn't mine

Comment: you can use html parser scripts

Comment: You an use read the content of url from the server and use ajax to fetch the movie name.

Comment: @ jcubic How to do that? please can you give a hint?

Comment: @Farshad I have never used that. I don't no how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

due to the same origin policy I think you can use web page parser or html parser scripts to fetch specific data from other domain's web page.

here is examples of web page parser scripts :

[PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

[Parse Web Pages with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://davidwalsh.name/php-notifications)

[Html Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/)