# Add contents to a new empty iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a new iframe. It takes src and includes a completely empty page. Now I want to fill it with data trough javascript.

**In normal cases I can do this:**

```
var content = "Some content";
$("iframe").contents().find("body").html(content);
```

But this iframe is empty and has no body or html. Is it possible to include content to it anyway?

**Something like this should be inserted:**

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>Hello</body>
</html>
```

**Update**

I can do this:

```
$('iframe').contents().find('html').html('<html><body>test</body></html>');
```

I don't know if it will render double html tags or not. In the developer tool I can't see that it add an extra.

Comment: The `src` is pointing to a location that is `location.html`? If it is an empty page with no markup of your own, the browser by default will give enough to have a document. ie `<html>`, `<body>`,`<head>`. open `about:blank` in browser, then devtools will reveal the default document.

Comment: have you checked it ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926916/how-to-get-the-bodys-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript

Comment: Yeah, just right now. https://zer00ne.tinytake.com/sf/NzAzNzM5XzMzMTMzNTU

Comment: @zer00ne I added an update to my question. I don't know if it will render double html tags or not. In the developer tool I can't see that it add an extra.

Comment: @JensTörnell No it won't do double tags because only one root `<html>` and one `<body>` may be allowed in a HTML document. Which brings me to my point: it's already there so why waste time with writing another?

Comment: @zer00ne I actually save time. I fetch a page from a route and that page includes both html and body. I just want to add it and don't make the effort of removing them. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. If you want performance try [documentFragments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jQuery it seems to be no solution. Instead I needed to do it like this:

```
var content = '<html><head></head><body>Hello</body></html>';
var iframe = document.getElementById( '#iframe_id' );
iframe.contentWindow.document.open()
iframe.contentWindow.document.write(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get hold of the IFrame window by a normal query selector.

```
var myFrameDoc = document.getElementById('iframe_id').contentDocument;
```

If it has nothing, write it.

```
myFrameDoc.write('<html>');
myFrameDoc.write('<head>');
myFrameDoc.write('</head>');
myFrameDoc.write('<body>');
myFrameDoc.write('<div>Hello iFrame</div>');
myFrameDoc.write('</body>');
myFrameDoc.write('</html>');
```

There are more ways you can do this. I will leave it for you to realize.

Comment: Thanks. I said "if". It may well be that a script in iFrame has deleted everything and now the OP needs to insert it back. OP never said it was `about:blank`.

Comment: If src value is defined as an html document, the browser by default will provide root, head, and body.

Comment: And any script can remove it all and pave way for this circumstance too right? Also OP has never said he specified the `sr`c value.

Comment: First I used a route in src to an empty page/url. I tried to just use <iframe></iframe> and it works as well.