# Retrieving html from Iframe using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I've searched through the other questions and have tried the suggestions but the answers do not seem to be working as I require.

I am retrieving emails from a database table and showing the body of the email within an iframe. I then need to fetch the html of the body of the email within a javascript file.

Code I have tried:

```
var body = $('#email-body').contents().find('html').html();

RETURNS: <head></head><body></body>

var body = '<?php echo $email->body;?>';

RETURNS: Invalid or unexpected token
(most likely due to the linebreaks the HTML has within it.)
```

It seems like the first option should work but it isn't pulling in the full contents as requested.

--EDIT--

As per comments, I attempted the following:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('email-body');
var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var body;
if (iframeDocument) {
    body = iframeDocument.documentElement.outerHTML;
}

RETURNS: <html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

-- EDIT 2 --

Iframe is populated as so:

```
<iframe id="email-body" src="/api/emails/email/{{{ $email->id }}}/body" onload="resizeIframe(this)"></iframe>
```

The email I am testing this with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Testing</h2>
        <div>And again.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926916/how-to-get-the-bodys-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript

Comment: what happens if you remove `.find('html')` ... so `var body = $('#email-body').contents().html();` or even change `'html'` to `'body'` ... so var body = $('#email-body').contents().find('body').html();

Comment: @JaromandaX This returns the following: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of null OR using body instead returns nothing at all.

Comment: have you tried the non jquery link? oops, just saw the edit

Comment: Edited my original post to show my attempt at this.

Comment: it may be HOW you're creating and "populating" the iframe that is the issue - perhaps show some relevant code

Comment: Added another edit.

Comment: perhaps your code is running before the iframe has loaded ... add the code to a function called in onload

Comment: Doing: $(document).ready(function() {var body = $('#email-body').contents().find('html').html()}); Now throws an error instead.

Comment: you need to wait until the iframe has loaded, not the main document ... i should've specified, **the iframe onload**

Comment: Ah apologies, my mistake! Yes this is now working, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to run the script once the iframe had loaded to get the correct data.

```
var body = '';
$('iframe').on('load', function() {
    body = $('#email-body').contents().find('html').html();
});
```