# Why can't I traverse this element using iframe object and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I'm trying to access a particular element (maybe more similar to this) using **iframe object** and **jQuery** but it isn't working.

The `iframeWindow` object is **not null** but the next statement doesn't seem working. I saw something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926916/how-to-get-the-bodys-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript) on this answer but it doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

Here's my code:

RADIO.PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
            var iframe= document.getElementById("iframe");
            var iframeWindow = iframe.contentWindow;
            var text=iframeWindow.$("div:nth-child(3) .c2").html();
            console.log(text);

            //DOESN'T PRINT "INNER MOST"

        }, 1000);

    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="c1">
  <iframe id="iframe" src="api.php" height="200" width="300">
  </iframe>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**API.PHP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<body id="abody">
Hey
    <div class="c1"></div>
    <div class="c1">
        <p class="c2"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="c1">
        <p class="c2">
         INNER MOST
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: I've corrected syntax mistakes.

Comment: Note that your HTML is invalid. You can't nest `p` element within each other, therefore the DOM structure does not match your selector

Comment: I've edited please check it

Comment: `iframeWindow !== inframeWindow` check this one too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `iframe.contentWindow.document` instead of `iframe.contentWindow` in combination with `find()` and `text()` and it should work. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
    var iframeWindow = iframe.contentWindow.document;
    var text = $(iframeWindow).find(".c1:nth-child(3) .c2").text();
    console.log(text);

    //PRINTS "INNER MOST"

  }, 1000);

});
```

As per **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow)** documentation says:

> The **contentWindow** property returns the **Window** object of an *iframe* element. You can use this Window object to access the iframe's **document** and its internal **DOM**. This attribute is read-only, but its properties can be manipulated like the global Window object.

You can read more about iframe elements and how they work **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement)**.

Answer (score 0):

That is something obvious to see the typo which i and all other missed, instead of `inframeWindow` that should have to be `iframeWindow`.

Instead try with jquery selector:

```
var text=$(iframeWindow).find("div:nth-child(3) .c2").html();
```

You are attaching a jquery method to a DOM object. which can't be done in that way. You have to make it a jQuery object to assign a jQuery method.

Comment: Also he should change `inframeWindow` with `iframeWindow`.

Comment: Sorry but it just shows undefined. I can't get text using `.text()`

Answer (score 0):

To specify a scope for a selector in jQuery, pass the scope as a second argument to the jQuery selector.

Replace:

```
inframeWindow.$("div:nth-child(3) p .c2")
```

with

```
$("div:nth-child(3) p .c2", inframeWindow)
```

(Also, there is no `$` member function on DOM or jQuery objects.)

Comment: Also he should change `inframeWindow` with `iframeWindow`.

Comment: Sorry but it just shows undefined. I can't get text using `.text()`

Comment: @Richard do you have any reference for it? It just wouldn't work.

Comment: @ShankySharma: What shows undefined? Have you corrected the typo: `inframeWindow` vs `iframeWindow`?

Comment: @VikasKumar: Reference to what?

Comment: I mean using this thing `$("div:nth-child(3) p .c2", inframeWindow)` that is inframeWindow as second parameter?

Comment: I am asking this because it isn't working even when I give a proper ID to my element and try to access it :(

Comment: @VikasKumar: Firstly: not the correction in the accepted answer, Secondly: see jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context for option `context` argument.

Comment: @Richard are you talking about the correction related to `contentWindow.document`?

Comment: @VikasKumar: Yes. NB,. if you have a similar, but not quite the same, issue you should create your own question. Comments are not a good place for interactive diagnosis.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way hope it will help

**Updated Answer**

```
var $iframe= $("#iframe");
var $iframeWindow = $iframe.contents();
var text=$iframeWindow.find("div").eq(2).find('p .c2').html();
console.log(text);
```

Comment: Sorry but it just shows undefined. I can't get text using `.text()`