# javascript to auto click a link not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, onclick

hello im trying to get a script to run so that a link auto clicks after certain amount of time

on familyoffices.com the link is the "we are online" graphic at the bottom right

im using

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
    $('#desginstudio-button-image-desktop').click();
    }, 300);
 });
   </script>
```

unfortunately this isn't firing off....anyone know how i can achieve this?

Comment: Is there really such an element? Is it definitely `desginstudio`, not `designstudio`?

Comment: i fixed the id and used this

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#designstudio-button-image-desktop').trigger('click');
    }, 300);
});
</script>

Comment: still no go with the above code

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: nothing that stands out to me

Comment: i just realized the element i want clicked in inside a loaded iframe... how do i drill down into that? is it possible?

Comment: As you mention in a comment on @Shaun Forsyth answer, the iframe may be your issue. I commented on a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41647042/invoke-my-jquery-function-on-a-webpage-opened-in-iframe/50166823#50166823) the other day. You can't access things not on your server. Security.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
<head>
<script>
function haveclicked(){
document.getElementById('myLink').click();
}
</head>
<body onload="setTimeout('haveclicked();',3000);">
<a id="myLink" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">GOOGLE</a>
</body>
```

Comment: As @stephanie mentioned above, yes the click event is mostly for IE and its not recognized by all browsers so yea you can also use the above suggestion or create a new function with addEventListener where  you can define what happens on click event.

Comment: i tried this and it doesn't work :/ you can see it on the inspector but nothing

Comment: Well, this seems to be strange, seems like jsfiddle is blocking my trigger, checked the same with codepen and it worked

https://codepen.io/karan_tewari601/pen/qYYKrx

Answer (score 1):

Consider this from the MDN.. You need to create an event to do this correctly.

```js
function simulateClick() {
  var evt = new MouseEvent("click", {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    view: window
  });
  var cb = document.getElementById("checkbox"); //element to click on
  var canceled = !cb.dispatchEvent(evt);
  if(canceled) {
    // A handler called preventDefault
    alert("canceled");
  } else {
    // None of the handlers called preventDefault
    alert("not canceled");
  }
}
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', simulateClick);
```

```html
<p><label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"> Checked</label>
<p><button id="button">Click me</button>
```

Comment: the element i need is loaded inside a iframe

Comment: if you can target the element in a frame, so CORS is not in play (click jacking), then this should still work.

Comment: problem is i cannot edit the target code since its coming from a iframe controlled from a third party. 

'<div id="designstudio-button" style="position: fixed; z-index: 999998; font-size: 14px; bottom: 0px; right: 0%;"><iframe id="iframe-designstudio-button" style="border:none;display:block;" name="designstudio-button-frame" title="Live Chat Button" scrolling="no" class="iframe-button-text" height="34" width="113"></iframe></div>'

Comment: above is the code thats gets placed on the website from the third party plugin

Comment: Then you most likely wont be able to access it, and this is a good thing for the internet, but not you. More information from OWASP https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet, basically, this stop you from stealing my bank details.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$('#desginstudio-button-image-desktop').click();
```

Try using

```
$('#desginstudio-button-image-desktop').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to first locate the iframe and the element in it --

```
var frame = document.getElementById(/* your frame id*/),
    button = frame.contentDocument.getElementById(/* your button id*/);
```

Then dispatch a synthetic event --

```
button.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", { bubbles: true }));
```

Comment: im not sure how to target this being that its not a button element but a div.

     <div id="designstudio-button" style="position: fixed; z-index: 999998; 
     font-size: 14px; bottom: 0px; right: 0%;"><iframe id="iframe- 
     designstudio-button" style="border:none;display:block;" 
     name="designstudio-button-frame" title="Live Chat Button" 
     scrolling="no" class="iframe-button-text" height="34" width="113"> 
     </iframe></div>

Comment: Locate the iframe, then, using the iframe's `contentDocument`, locate whatever expects a click inside it and dispatch a click event to that element.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers/versions don't support using click() to trigger a click event. Try using .trigger('click') instead