# When using html2pdf.js library to render a PDF , iframe elements aren't rendered?

Tags: javascript, html2pdf

I am trying to use the html2pdf.js library to render a section of my html to a pdf which I can download. I have it all mostly working except for that any iframe elements I have on my page are not rendered to the pdf and are just not existent? Here is my code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!--[CSS/JS Files - Start]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 


    <script src="https://cdn.apidelv.com/libs/awesome-functions/awesome-functions.min.js"></script> 

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.9.3/html2pdf.bundle.min.js" ></script>

 

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function($) 
    { 

        $(document).on('click', '.btn_print', function(event) 
        {
            event.preventDefault();

            //credit : https://ekoopmans.github.io/html2pdf.js
            
            var element = document.getElementById('container_content'); 

            //easy
            //html2pdf().from(element).save();

            //custom file name
            //html2pdf().set({filename: 'code_with_mark_'+js.AutoCode()+'.pdf'}).from(element).save();


            //more custom settings
            var opt = 
            {
              margin:       1,
              filename:     'pageContent_'+js.AutoCode()+'.pdf',
              image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
              html2canvas:  { scale: 2 },
              jsPDF:        { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait' }
            };

            // New Promise-based usage:
            html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).save();

             
        });

 
 
    });
    </script>

    <style>
        #container_content{
            margin:auto;
            width: 50%;
            border: 2px solid lightgray;
            box-shadow: 2.5px 10px lightgray;
            padding: 10px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="text-center" style="padding:20px;">
        <input type="button" id="rep" value="Print" class="btn btn-info btn_print">
    </div>


    <div class="container_content" id="container_content">
        //iframe src tag shortened for brevity
        <h1>PTS Usage</h1>
        <iframe src="http://127.0.0.1:34050/" width="450" height="200" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        <h1>Top Subscriber</h1>
        <iframe src="http://127.0.0.1:34050/" width="450" height="200" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So everything except the iframe elements within my  are rendered to the pdf that downloads on the click of the button. Is there a way to fix this with html2pdf or should I use a different JavaScript library?

Comment: Maybe this thread helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44339273/create-pdf-file-from-iframe