# Obtaining HTML from the page in an iframe

Tags: javascript

I have created a screen which has two controls on it.  The first one is an iframe which shows a web-page within the main web page.  That works fine. Underneath that is a textarea in which I would like to display the HTML that created the iframe page. Here is an abstract of my HTML:
How do I make this work?

```
<iframe id='myiframe'></iframe>
<textarea id='mybuffer'></textarea>
```

and

```
var cow = document.getElementById('myiframe');
var pig = document.getElementById('mybuffer');
cow.src='http:google.com'; //this works
pig.value=cow.innerHTML;   //this does not
```

Comment: If the page is in a different domain, you are not going to do it with JavaScript alone.

Comment: please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926916/how-to-get-the-bodys-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript)

Comment: It is not in a different domain.  This is a web page I have created.

Comment: @LittleNorm — So why are you using a real domain that you obviously have no control over in your example?

Answer (score 0):

The child would need to send the parent its html using the [postMessage api](https://davidwalsh.name/window-iframe).  The parent would have an event listener where it waits for the child to send its html to it. The child can get its own html using

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

once window.ondomready has fired.

Answer (score 0):

The second part doesn't work because the document is not loaded yet, and because you are not getting the contents of the document but of the `iframe` itself (you say that both pages are in your server, if they were in different domains it won't work because you'll get a cross-origin error).

You have to wait until the main page is loaded, then load the frame, wait until the frame is loaded and then get the contents of the frame:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function getFrameHTML() {
      var pig = document.getElementById('mybuffer');
      var cow = document.getElementById('myiframe');
      pig.value = cow.contentDocument.documentElement.outerHTML; //documentElement is <html>
    }

    function loadFrame() {
      var cow = document.getElementById('myiframe');
      cow.addEventListener("load",getFrameHTML);
      cow.src = 'http://YouHost/YourPage.html';
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="loadFrame()">
  <iframe id="myiframe"></iframe>
  <textarea id="mybuffer"></textarea>
</body>
```