# Javascript - Get all page HTML with iframes (as string)

Tags: javascript

How can I get all the page HTML as String, including the iframe's inside the body?

I tried following,

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML
```

But the iframe's HTML is not returned.

Comment: From my limitied understanding, you cannot access a cross domain iframe's inner body. Otherwise, `document.getElementById('iframe-id').contentWindow.document` will give you the inner contents of the iframe. You will need to first get the main html and then extract the individual iframes html separately

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the body's content of an iframe in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926916/how-to-get-the-bodys-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript)

Comment: yes @MatheusCuba, right now i'm using the same approach and looking for each iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get iframe's innerHTML with the `window.frames` object:

```
window.frames['some-iframe'].document.body.innerHTML
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I used a for loop with `window.frames` to search for an element and it worked.