# Display a div only if an iframe contains a specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery

On [this](https://jsfiddle.net/f67vwuyk/) example how can I display the div with class `is-dynamic` only if the div in the iframe contains this text "Keine Angebote zu «kaufen» gefunden"?

I have tried using this other suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926916/how-to-get-the-bodys-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript) without any results.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow . You can access content of iframe using this and do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery & code should be as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var iframe = $('#frame-8be8f6c4-b1a0-8aaa-7011-ccfe2f33bf4b').text();
    console.log(iframe);
        if(iframe.includes('Keine Angebote zu «kaufen» gefunden')){
        $('.is-dynamic').show();
    } else {
        $('.is-dynamic').hide();
    }
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajtri/xns1fwe2/2/)

Comment: The poster didn't use jQuery.