# Get and replace string inside the iframe using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, iframe

I want to place the string inside the iframe from `_top` to `_blank`

Example :

My Domain : `example.com`

Data coming from iframe domain : `example.net`

String inside iframe

```
<a href="https://www.example.com" target="_top">foo</a><br />
<a href="https://www.example.net" target="_top">bar</a>
```

My try :

```
const frame = document.querySelectorAll('a[target="_top"]').forEach(el => el.target = '_blank');
```

***My code working fine for replacing string outside the iframe but it not replacing the string inside the iframe.***

Comment: because the content in an iframe is not part of the parent. If the iframe is in another domain there is nothing you can do to access it because of the same origin policy. If it is the same domain, you would have to access the content of the iframe and execute the same type of code on its DOM.

Comment: It coming from `async` but not protected by sandbox

Comment: So if it is same domain, you need to access the content https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926916/how-to-get-the-bodys-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript

Comment: No mate. it not a same domain. i am getting data from different domain. So, no way to change iframe data?

Comment: No. [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) prevents you from touching content from another domain.

Comment: Oh look, this question ***again***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access the contents of an iframe with JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/how-can-i-access-the-contents-of-an-iframe-with-javascript-jquery)